# Why is my aspect not displaying the full data?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.5, slope, altitude, aspect

[image]

[image]

I am trying to get the slope aspect for the altitude shown above. Can someone please advise me on why this may not be working properly?

Comment: Try to check environment settings.

Comment: Agreed. My guess is you have something smaller than your input DEM set as the processing extent or raster mask.